# Undefined method errors in obfuscated code

Tags: java

I've got some obfuscated code and I'm trying to figure out what the program is trying to do when accessing some made up methods. The code is decompiled by request of the program owner, so I'm not trying to hack into anything.

I've got a file in here that has many objects of the type MenuItem that are trying to access methods that just don't exist. I assume this must be due to the obfuscation, but I'd like to see if anyone has any ideas as to what the program is trying to do or how I can go about attempting to fix it.

I'll just go with one example and the object is declared as such:

```
public class t extends JFrame {
  Panel a = new u(this);
  MenuItem ag;
  // There's a ton of other code in here but I'm trying to just keep the relevant information.
}
```

The issue is first seen later on in the class when trying to use these two objects in some function definitions:

```
  public void o() {
    ag.a(this.l);
  }
  
  public void p() {
    ag.a(this.l, true);
  }
```

This is what throws the error: `The method a(r, boolean) is undefined for the type MenuItem`

I'm not actually sure if the declaration of `Panel a` above has anything to do with this, as I think it's just trying to access the method `a()` inside of the MenuItem class, which obviously doesn't exist.

I've read through the methods of both the [MenuItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MenuItem.html) and [Panel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Panel.html) classes but haven't found anything that seems to relate to this made-up method.

There are also entirely separate function definitions, all named `a`, that take a variety of parameters in this `t` class. Not sure how you can have more than one function with the same name in one class, but it's there. I also don't know how they would be accessed through the `ag` object.

I'm just hoping someone may be able to help me with some kind of explanation as to what's going on or where I should go from here.

Comment: "Not sure how you can have more than one function with the same name in one class" - java supports method overloading, no problem there.

Comment: Well, if the compiled code worked, then it is the process of decompilation that is the problem here. You could start by telling us which decompiler you used (Fernflower?), and how exactly you got to your currently broken decompiled version.

Comment: Possibly the obfuscator replaced/wrapped `java.awt.MenuItem` with some custom class that does have a method named `a`, and something "fixed" the imports to point back to the standard version.

Comment: @Hulk I just used JD-GUI http://java-decompiler.github.io/

Comment: Is the program-owner the same as the program-creator? If not, does the program-owner have the right to decompile the code? If he is the creator, why doesn't he have the full source code?

Comment: @NomadMaker Yes. I don't know why he didn't give the source code and I initially asked about it which is when he said that it should be in the files that he gave me and to decompile it. Weird situation.